# How do I switch to a completely new Apple ID?

Tags: ios

My parents and I all have iPhones. My mother and I used to have them both authorized to the same account which was mine. Now they want to authorize their phones to there own accounts. They have done so with there new iPhone 5's but it is still asking for my Apple ID. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I may have over-edited this, but some details aren't entirely clear. Did they activate their iPhone 5 via your Apple ID? And now you're trying to change the Apple ID after-the-fact?

Answer (score 3):

When I changed my ID on my iphone, I didn't see an "edit" option either.  So maybe my experience will help you, I hope.  After going to Settings/iCloud, I was told to scroll down to the bottom of the page where it says DELETE ACCOUNT.  After deleting my son's account from my phone, I was able to enter my own ID.  It took a few tries and some time while it tried to validate the new ID and then it told me to go to my email on my computer to respond for verification.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

That happened to me when my wife got her iPhone.

Any apps that you downloaded with your Apple ID will require that ID and password when they are updated.

The only (legitimate) way around this is to have them delete all of the apps that you downloaded with your Apple ID and re-buy or re-download them with theirs.